# Button action is not working on subView

Tags: ios, swift, button, filtering, subview

In one of my iOS project, I have added a subview for Filter ViewController(subview) on my Feed ViewController(main view) programmatically.

There are few button on Filter ViewController to select price, city etc.

The outlets are connected but when I am trying to shoot button action, it is not working. 
I have also enabled the isUserInteractionEnabled but still it is not working.

Acc. to me, this is something related to subview on a view !! but to resolve this. Can you suggest me how to shoot a button action of subview it happen ?

```
class FilterViewController: BaseUIViewController{

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     cityButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   }

   @IBAction func selectCity(_ sender: Any)
   {
    print("selectCity action")
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and let us know what you already tried before we can help you

Comment: Please remember to use the add childViewController method when adding a view controller as a subview inside another view controller. It would be `feedViewController.addChildViewController(childController: filterViewController)` in your case

Comment: @DatForis Ok. I will try.
Thank you for replying.

Comment: check your button not going outside to frame

Comment: @HarshalValanda OK. Thank you. I will check

Comment: @DatForis It is giving me this error. What am I missing ?

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<RentInApp.FilterViewController: 0x7fa8abd300e0> should have parent view controller:<RentInApp.AdsViewController: 0x7fa8abd1bc00> but actual parent is:<RentInApp.AdsViewController: 0x7fa8abe0d1b0>'

Comment: @HarshalValanda It isn't going out of the frame.

Comment: @dedicatedCoder you don't add a viewController as childController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your FilterViewController as subview to your ViewController using the code below

```
filterViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
self.view.addSubview(filterViewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(filterViewController)
filterViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: @dedicatedcoder : Am glad I could be of some help :) Happy coding

Comment: @xhinoda : am glad I could help :)

Comment: for any1 else needing this solution. you need 
self.addChildViewController(filterViewController.init())

Answer (score 0):

@**SandeepBhandari** solution is still valid for similar issues.

These `UIViewController` extensions will be useful.

```
extension UIViewController {

func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController, containerView: UIView) {
    addChild(viewController)
    containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
    viewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}

func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    viewController.removeFromParent()
} 

}
```